# Oracle apex and jira integration

Tags: jira, apex, jira-rest-api

My jira is like: `https://jira.oraclecorp.com/jira/browse/FINTECH-63740`

What I want is to integrate the Jira with Oracle apex tool. So I wanted to create a `Web credentials` in `Workspace Utilities`. So how can I get the client id and client secret for the jira to invoke apis?